HTML tags < class="mk-metro-portfolio-title"> appearing incorrectly in my WordPress website
I'm encountering a problem on my WordPress website where some HTML tags are appearing incorrectly as < class="mk-metro-portfolio-title"> instead of <div class="mk-metro-portfolio-title">. This issue is causing unexpected formatting in certain parts of my site.
Here's what I've observed and tried so far:
Issue Details: When inspecting the HTML code of the affected pages, I noticed that certain tags are missing the <div> prefix, resulting in < class="mk-metro-portfolio-title"> instead of <div class="mk-metro-portfolio-title">.
Context: I'm using a WordPress theme and possibly some plugins that manage portfolio or custom post type displays. The incorrect tags seem to be related to these sections of my site.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Inspected theme files (wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/) and plugin files but couldn't pinpoint where these tags are being generated.
Reviewed functions.php for any modifications related to portfolio or custom post types but didn't find any direct cause.
Expected Outcome: I need assistance in identifying where these incorrect tags are being generated so that I can correct them to <div class="mk-metro-portfolio-title">.
Could someone please guide me on how to locate and edit the source of these tags within WordPress? Any advice on where to look or how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.
